# How to add to devise model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I create a user model via command `rails generate devise Users`.

I want my `Users` model to stay the same however I want to add more columns but I'm not sure how and I am still a bit confused at the moment. I am pretty new to Ruby on Rails. I am not sure what command I am supposed you run after these changes are made as well. I think it is `rake db:migrate` in order to update the database.

I want to be able to add

```
name - string
address - string
username - string ..
```

According to this example in the documentation,

```
class AddDetailsToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :products, :part_number, :string    
    add_column :products, :price, :decimal
  end
end
```

Inside the `change` method, add columns `part_number` (string) and `price` (decimal) to the `products` table

Would this

file: `20141011161019_devise_create_users.rb`

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.inet     :current_sign_in_ip
      t.inet     :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't change the existing migration. You want to create a new migration with the command `rails generate migration MigrationName`, and then follow the [Active Record Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) Rails Guide, which gives lots of examples on how to add database columns.

Comment: Does the line `add_column :products, :part_number, :string` translate to add column part_number (string) to the products table?

Comment: Yes. The first parameter is the table name, the second is the field name, and the third is the type.

Answer (score 3):

First, run `rake db:migrate`. This will run the migration prepared by devise on your database.

After that, just add more fields to your model, just the same as you would if you'd never installed devise. The first step is to generate a new migration. Run this at the command line:

`bin/rails generate migration AddNameAddressUsernameToUsers name:string address:string username:string`

This will create a new migration file. You should then run that migration file on your database, with `rake db:migrate` again. After that, you should be able to refer to those new model fields in your controller and views.

While you could do it all in a single migration, it's generally better to keep your migrations small and discrete. This makes it easier to resolve issues if anything goes wrong.

Comment: This is what ended my head banging. Thanks !